# Cannot connect to web server with node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm trying to follow the Angular tutorial and I can't pass step 00 part 2. I used node.js and try to run the command scripts/web-server.js. It just shows me "..." and when I go to the local host port 8000 it says couldn't connect.

any ideas?

Comment: If that script runs correctly, it prints "Http Server running at http://localhost:8000/" to the terminal. Which version of node do you have?

Comment: Despite your reference to this tutorial, please show us what your code looks like and how you call it.

Comment: @ksimons I used the latest version which is 10.20

Comment: @luksch I didn't use any code as of yet, i assume the web-server.js is already made somewhere

Comment: So from the root of the angular-phonecat directory you type `node ./scripts/web-server.js` and it doesn't work?

Comment: @ksimons I type it in the node.js terminal actually, I'll try to do it from the phonechat directory, EDIT: tried it I went on the git bash, changed the directory to angular-phonecat and it gave me this error module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\scripts\web-server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'll fix your problem. I've made it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to:

```
git clone git://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
cd angular-phonecat
node ./scripts/web-server.js
```

Comment: yeah did exactly that, it gave me a module error module.js:340 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\scripts\web-server.js' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) at startup (node.js:119:16) at node.js:901:3

Comment: Are you sure you're typing it exactly as above? I've just tried it on Windows as well and it works perfectly. Just do it in a normal Windows command prompt.

Comment: AH I just for the "." before the /script and it work perfectly now thank you

Comment: What worked and didnt for me:

**Worked**: added the angular-phonecat directory using the tutorial, with
git clone --depth=14 https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git

**Didn't work**:the git command above (in a different directory):fatal: unable to connect to github.com

**Didn't work**: the node command "node ./scripts/web-server.js" (even copy/pasting, with "." included. Error message as described 3 comments above by user2809321

BTW Do I really need to get node.js working in order to use angular.js? Other tutorials out there just include a link to the library on Google

Answer (score 0):

So the URL you are meant to enter into the browser is actually `http://localhost:8000/angular-phonecat/app/index.html`

It depends on the directory you are in, if you just put: `http://localhost:8000` in you will be able to navigate to the directory and open the index.html graphically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial
and follow the steps there.
Specifically do the following - 
In command prompt
navigate to your solution directory - i.e. Users\"<>"\angular-phonecat
and run

**npm install**

This command will download the following tools, into the node_modules directive:

Bower - client-side code package manager

http-server - simple local static web server

Karma - unit test runner

protractor - end 2 end test runner

and then run the following command -

**npm start**

and now you should be able to navigate to 
**localhost:8000/app/index.html** on your browser !